# Customize GravityForm HTML (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any way to customize the HTML form generated by GravityForms wordpress plugin?

By default fields are wrapped in `<li>`

I want the form to look like a bail agreement.

Comment: Display your `<li>`s differently? It's hard to help you when you haven't provided any of your code.

Comment: My current form is -> http://ez1bail.zenbizsolutions.com/test-form/
And I want it to look like a bail Agreement, where input fields are inline with text